# Node module.exports returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am having an issue with Node.js and `module.exports`. I understand that `module.exports` is a call to return an object, that object having whatever properties it is assigned.

If I have a file structure like this:

```
// formatting.js

function Format(text) {
    this.text = text;
}

module.exports = Format;
```

with this:

```
// index.js

var formatting = require('./formatting');
```

Is there a way to initialize a `Format` object and use it like this?

```
formatting('foo');
console.log(formatting.text);
```

Whenever I try to do it that way, I get an error that says `formatting is not a function`. I then have to do it like this:

```
var x = new formatting('foo');
console.log(x.text);
```

which seems cumbersome.

In modules like `keypress` and `request`, they can be used right out of the gate, like this:

```
var keypress = require('keypress');

keypress(std.in);
```

or

```
var request = require('request);

request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
  }
})
```

How does this work?

Comment: Does this work?
 var formatting = require('./formatting.js');

Comment: In your code you are returning function constructor from formatting module. Instead you want to return it as a object so that you can directly use it.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @apizzimenti Check my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest wrapping the `new` call in it's own function then returning that:

```
function Format(text) {
  this.text = text;
}

function formatting(text) {
  return new Format(text);
}

module.exports = formatting;
```

This way you should still be able to do:

```
var format = formatting('foo');
console.log(format.text);
```

**Edit**:

In terms of the `request` stuff, one thing you have to remember is that in JavaScript, functions are still objects. This means you can still add properties and methods to them. This is what they're doing in `request` though overall it's a bit too complicated to explain every detail in this answer. From what I can tell, they add a bunch of methods (functions on an object) to the `request` function. This is why you can immediately call those methods like `request(blah, blah).pipe(blah).on(blah)` Based on what's returned from calling the `request` function, you can chain some of the other methods on the back of it. When you're using request it's not an object, it's a function (but still technically an object). To demonstrate how functions are still objects and how it's possible to add methods to them, check out this simple example code:

```
function hey(){
  return;
}

hey.sayHello = function(name) {
  console.log('Hello ' + name);
} 

hey.sayHello('John'); //=> Hello John
```

This is basically what they're doing, just a lot more complicated and with a lot more stuff going on.

Comment: Yes, that works, but can the object instead be initialized by calling `formatting('foo')` instead of `var format = formatting('foo')`?

Comment: What do you mean? When you initialize it don't you want to set the returned object to a variable? Yes I guess it's possible to do something like `console.log(formatting('foo').text)` but what would be the point of that?

Comment: Right, I see. In your second code block, `formatting` is a reference to `require('./formatting')`, correct?

Comment: Yes, if at the top with all of your other requires you did `var formatting = require('./formatting');`, that's where I got the `formatting()` function from.

Comment: Also, if you're curious about how `request` works, you should check out the code that makes it run: https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/index.js

Comment: The reason I came up with this question is because I'd been browsing the `request` repo for hours and didn't understand how it could return an object and have it immediately able to have functions called on it. I looked through `index.js`, `request.js`, and a few files in `/lib`, and didn't understand how it worked (I couldn't really follow the different references to `module.exports` and `exports` throughout each file).

Comment: Check out my new edit. I'm sure there's much more that someone can elaborate about but hopefully this helps you understand how `request` works a little better. I wouldn't feel comfortable trying to explain it any further, because I'd be way out of my league.

Answer (score 3):

```
module.exports = Format;
```

This will return the `Format` constructor when you will `require('./formatting')`

On the other hand the code below will return an instance of `Format`, which you can directly call methods on:

```
module.exports = new Format();
```

Comment: If I do this and then do `formatting('text')`and I try to console.log the `text` property of the object, it still says that `formatting is not a function`. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, because once you create an object out of a Constructor with `new`, it's no longer a function but an object created by applying your *Constructor* function to a new object. So if you want to have a module that is at the same time an object and a function like jQuery for example, the constructor pattern isn't the right way to do it. Instead, first export a function and then attach properties to it.

Comment: @lleaff so if I do the second option and then in index.js run `format('foo')`, then it will assign 'foo' to the `text` property? `module.exports` is returning an empty instance of the class, and then calling its constructor function with `format('foo')` correctly assigns the property?

Comment: @apizzimenti Checkout Sam's answer I think this is what you mean to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

module formatting:

```
function Format() {
    this.setter = function(text) {
      this.text = text;
    }
    this.show = function() {
      console.log(this.text);
    } 
}
//this says I want to return empty object of Format type created by Format constructor.

module.exports = new Format();
```

index.js

```
var formatting = require('./formatting');
formatting('Welcome');
console.log(formatting.show());
```

Comment: Could you say some detail for `module.exports = new Format();`?

Comment: Does this work for you? It still returns the error `formatting is not a function` on the line that `formatting('Welcome')` is called.

Comment: As fromatting is object of format class so we can't pass 'text' to object, we need a setter method for it.