# Node.js pass variable/object from one module and return it

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, routes, return

I am using a `node.js` express framework and initially wrote the get database password/hash and compare form password/hash in one route file. Now I want to pass a `userName` to a separate module. The module should accept a `userName` and return the corresponding password/hash from the database.

Before breaking the functions out into their own modules, we return the hash and pass it to the next function (`passHash`) and the code worked just fine. Now that I've separated the functions from the db calls, I cannot figure out how to return the hash back to the original function.

With the functions broken out into two separate files, I can successfully pass `userName` to the database module (it console logs the `username`/`hash`), but I cannot return the user's password/hash back to the original function in the original route. I've read many posts on how to use `require` to pass "OR" return variables/objects from one module to another, but nothing on how to pass a variable "AND" return the post function data.

Here are some of the resources that I consulted when creating these files

1.) [Accepted answer was easy to follow (this is the model I used)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151693/passing-arguments-to-require-when-loading-module)

2.) [Advanced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534702/node-js-use-of-module-exports-as-a-constructor)

3.) [Example most answers show one way return functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120117/sharing-modifying-a-variable-between-multiple-files-node-js)

4.) [Seems to have the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504541/node-module-exports-returns-undefined)

Additionally, I have tried returning the password/hash in several arrangements; Create an object and return properties. Return the object, and assign the object to a variable and extract the property similar to link 4 Above.

Below are:

1.) The Modularized Database function (`databaseLoginUser.js`)

2.) The Original Route that calls the Modularized function (`databaseLogin.js`)

3.) The console output (no error just hangs waiting for the next function)

```js
//databaseLoginUser.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports.getModuleFunction = function(userName, callback) {
  queryUser(userName);

  function queryUser(userName) {
    console.log('In Query User; ');
    var database = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
      port: "3306",
      user: "UserName",
      password: "Password",
      database: "Students",
      multipleStatements: true
    });

    database.connect();

    console.log('test');

    database.query('SELECT StudentUsername, StudentPassword FROM STUDENT WHERE StudentUsername = ?', userName, function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      //console.log(rows);
      console.log('Database Returned User: ' + rows[0].StudentUsername);
      console.log('Database Returned Password: ' + rows[0].StudentPassword);
      var hashFromDatabaseBuffer = Buffer.from(rows[0].StudentPassword);
      returnPassHash(hashFromDatabaseBuffer);
      return returnPassHash;
    })

    function returnPassHash(hashFromDatabaseBuffer) {
      console.log('Do I get here?; ');
      return hashFromDatabaseBuffer;
    }
  }
};
```

`queryPass` is the function that calls and returns the other module's password property, and I have written this a few different ways, but settled on posting this version of the function call for brevity.

```js
//loginUser.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var async = require('async');
var app = express();
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var securePassword = require('secure-password');
var database = require('./db');
var queryPass = require('./databaseLoginUser');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  'use strict';
  console.log('in the login user get route');
  res.render('signUp');
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  'use strict';
  console.log('in Login Route');
  var userName = req.body.userName;
  var preHashPass = req.body.password;

  queryPass.getModuleFunction(userName, function(data) {
    passHash('', '', data)
  });

  function passHash(userName, preHashPass, hashFromDatabaseBuffer) {
    // Initialise our password policy
    var pwd = securePassword()
    var postPassHash = Buffer.from(preHashPass);

    // Register user
    pwd.hash(postPassHash, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) throw err
      // Save hash somewhere
      console.log('Form Password Hashed:');
      console.log(hash);

      pwd.verify(postPassHash, hashFromDatabaseBuffer, function(err, result) {
        console.log('Verify Result: ');
        console.log(result);
        if (err) throw err
        if (result === securePassword.INVALID) {
          return res.render('index');
          return console.log('Imma call the cops')
          res.render('index');
        } else {
          if (result === securePassword.INVALID_UNRECOGNIZED_HASH) return console.error('This hash was not made with secure-password. Attempt legacy algorithm')
          if (result === securePassword.VALID) console.log('Yay you made it')
          if (result === securePassword.VALID_NEEDS_REHASH) {
            console.log('Yay you made it, wait for us to improve your safety')

            pwd.hash(hashFromDatabase, function(err, improvedHash) {
              if (err) console.error('You are authenticated, but we could not improve your safety this time around')

              // Save improvedHash somewhere
              hash = improvedHash;
            })
          }

          var verifiedHash = hash;
          console.log('verifiedHash: ');
          console.log(verifiedHash);

          //Give User Auth Token Here
          console.log('You Get an auth Token: ');
          res.render('studentDash');
        }

      }) // pwd.verify


    });
    pwd.hash
  }; // pass hash
})

module.exports = router;
```

Console Output from Server 
(note the passwords are dummy data)

**Console output**

```
[nodemon] starting node ./bin/www 
GET /LogoWithLayersTiny.png 304 1.124 ms - - 
in Login Route 
In Query User; 
test 
Database Returned User: bb 
Database Returned Password: "HashParametersRemoved"$WItArkxi20QeSHlGhUK2lQ$PY74Axv6cOvFD‌​FiHmZ6EwT0RMgLkDOb1W‌​6CVBssE1tk 
Do I get here?
```

Comment: Could not include console output because it was improperly formatted and cannot edit post. Including console output here: 
`
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`

GET /LogoWithLayersTiny.png 304 1.124 ms - -
in Login Route
In Query User;
test
Database Returned User: bb
Database Returned Password: "HashParametersRemoved"$WItArkxi20QeSHlGhUK2lQ$PY74Axv6cOvFDFiHmZ6EwT0RMgLkDOb1W6CVBssE1tk
Do I get here?;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to call `callback` in databaseLoginUser.js passing the data.
Something like this:

```
// databaseLoginUser.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports.getModuleFunction = function (userName, callback) {
    queryUser(userName);
    function queryUser(userName) {
        console.log('In Query User; ');
         var database = mysql.createConnection({
            host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
            port: "3306",
            user: "UserName",
            password: "Password",
            database: "Students",
            multipleStatements: true
        });

        database.connect();

        database.query('SELECT StudentUsername, StudentPassword FROM STUDENT WHERE StudentUsername = ?', userName, function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) { console.log(err); }
            console.log('Database Returned User: ' + rows[0].StudentUsername);
            console.log('Database Returned Password: ' + rows[0].StudentPassword);
            var hashFromDatabaseBuffer = Buffer.from(rows[0].StudentPassword);
            callback(hashFromDatabaseBuffer); // This call.
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks I will update. This makes sense since the buffer call will take some time to return.

Comment: Wow thanks. This was literally that simple. I may make some changes to make the code cleaner, but this makes the main login module much less monolithic! Hopefully this will help others looking to make more modular code.